# Creating PayRun Returning Status 503 Error

Tags: xero-api

For the past number of months, I was successfully posting to the Following Payroll NZ PayRun Endpoint.

`https://api.xero.com/payroll.xro/2.0/PayRuns`

Request Body

`{"payrollCalendarID":"7e9cb6dd-4c3a-4d50-8ffd-96b07c397e2e","payRunType":"Scheduled"}`

(Calendar ID is correct)

However, everytime I get the following error message as a response. I am using the xero-php library, however, I get the same response when I create a manual request also.

`{"Title":"An error occurred","Detail":"An error occurred in Xero. Check the API Status page http://status.developer.xero.com for current service status.","Status":500,"Instance":"40aae479-cedc-4eb6-a7bf-09ff3cca93e4"}`

However, of course, there is never anything to read at the developer status page, and the history explorer page does not provide any insight.

Does anyone know what may be causing this error with no debugging information?

[image: Xero History Log]

[image: Xero Error Message]